# Trace theorem for general Sobolev spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces

I am reading Evans' book on Partial differential equations. Where he proves the existence of trace operator $T:W^{1,p}(\Omega) \rightarrow L^p(\Omega),$ for $1 \leq p <\infty.$
Does there exist such an operator for fractional Sobolev spaces or Sobolev spaces with negative order?

If yes, where can I find the details?

If not, why is it not possible to define the traces?

Comment: Googling the phrase _traces for fractional Sobolev spaces_ led me to results in a very general setting (variable exponents), so I'm sure you'd benefit from googling it a little bit further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple case to understand why it is sometimes not possible to define traces is when the space is $L^p$. Then the functions are defined only almost everywhere so the trace has no meaning. On the other hand, a meaning can easily be given when a the space embeds in the space of continuous functions (which is the case of $W^{s,p}(\mathbb R^d)$ when $s > d/p$).

For the case $p=2$, in the book of L. Tartar, *An Introduction to Sobolev Spaces and Interpolation Spaces*, you will find a chapter about trace for $H^s$ spaces when $s>1/2$. In the case $s=1/2$, there is an interesting special space $H^{1/2}_{0,0}$.

More generally, you can find the result in Triebel's book *Theory of Function Spaces II*, Section 4.4. If you do not know Besov and Triebel Lizorkin generalizations of Sobolev's spaces, you just have to know that

- Bessel fractional Sobolev spaces are $H^{s,p} = F^{s}_{p,2}$
- Fractional Sobolev-Slobodeckij spaces are $W^{s,p} = F^{s}_{p,p} = B^{s}_{p,p}$.

Then the result is that if $p\in[1,\infty]$ and $s> 1/p$, then the trace is continuous from $F^s_{p,q}$ to $F^{s-1/p}_{p,p}$.